# Javascript - Stop Slideshow timeout

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slideshow that displays one image each second

But I wanted a "stop button" in order to.....stop the carousel XD I'm working on it but I separated the both functions (one for carousel, one for buttons).

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div id="gallerie2">
    <img id="first2" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/150/150/2"><br/>
    <div id="vignette">
        <img class="second2" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/150/150/6">
        <img class="second2" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/150/150/4">
        <img class="second2" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/150/150/3">
        <img class="second2" src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/150/150/2">
        <img class="second2" src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/150/150/1">
        <img class="second2" src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/150/150/4">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="controlSlideShow">
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

**Here is the Javascript for the slideshow (it works perfectly, that's not the problem)**

```
var index = 0;
    setInterval(function nextSlide(){
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("second2");
        var firstSlide = document.getElementById("first2");
        firstSlide.src = slides[index].src;
        index++;
        if(index == slides.length){
            index = 0;   
        }
    }, 1000);
```

**Then here is the Javascript for buttons where the problem is**

```
    document.getElementById("controlSlideShow").addEventListener('click', controlSlideShow);
    function controlSlideShow(e){
        switch(e.target.id){
            case 'stop':
                console.log("clickStop");
                clearTimeout(nextSlide);
            break;
            case 'start': console.log("start");
            break;   
        }
    }
```

I'm working on those buttons but I can't call the nextSlide() function a clearTimeout() in order to stop the slideshow.

Thank you for taking time to my problem. Can you explain me after resolving ? I really want where is(are) my mistake(s), not just take the solution. =)

Here is the jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k3g19dbo/

Comment: controlSlideShow is a div, try adding a event listener on button with id `stop`

Comment: @RehbanKhatri It's not a problem becasue I use the e parameter in order to target my id in my div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you need to pass to `clearInterval` (not `clearTimeout`) is not the name of the function you passed to `setInterval`, but the value that `setInterval` returns. So do this:

```
var timerId = setInterval(function nextSlide(){
     // ... etc
}, 1000);
// ...
clearInterval(timerId);
// ...
```

NB: `clearTimeout` would also work in most browsers, but it just makes more sense to call `clearInterval` when you used `setInterval`, and `clearTimeout` when you used `setTimeout`.

Comment: I understand the logic, thank you, I will be more careful =) but I can't call the variable If I have a start button right ? I'm learning Javascript, so I'm not as good as I want but If I want to replay, I can't call the function that is in a variable timerID with something like : setInterval(timerId).

Comment: The timer ID is only useful for stopping an existing interval, not to start it. To start it you must reference a function as argument.